# What are the different styles of bonsai trees?

Tags: bonsai

I am interested in bonsai, but I'm having difficulty finding the design that I want because when searching the internet most of the bonsai styles don't have pictures.

Could we create a compilation of bonsai styles here? It will be much better if we can add pictures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Basic styles](http://www.bonsaimary.com/basic-bonsai-styles.html)

1. Formal Upright Style (Chokkan)

[image]

2. Informal Upright (Moyogi)

[image]

3. Slant (Shakan)

[image]

4. Cascade - Kengai

[image]

5. Windswept - Fukinagashi

[image]

6. Raft Style - Ikadabuki

[image]
[image]

7. Forest Bonsai - Yose-ue

[image]
[image]

8. Broom Style - Hokidachi

[image]

## [Unique Bonsai Styles](http://www.bonsaimary.com/bonsai-styles.html)

> At first glance, many bonsai styles can be identified by the basic
>   descriptions.
>
> They may also be combinations of shapes, such as a 'windswept
>   semi-cascade.'
>
> Or they may be something totally unique, such as this pine by bonsai
>   artist Walter Pall (Germany.)

**Windswept Semi-Cascade**

[image]

**Root-Over-What**

[image]

**Figurines and Bonsai**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here is a good picture list of Bonsai styles:

[image]

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much! I don't have much time to edit my answer in a complete styles. :)

Comment: No problem. You're answer below is better, I just went to quick and dirty route. Sometimes it's helpful to see everything right there together, but your pictures definitely have more impact.